# Where can I get the list of available sku_names of Azure MySQL DB for using Terraform

Tags: mysql, azure, terraform

I'm writing a Terraform script for creating Azure MySQL. While selecting the sku_name section, I couldn't find how to select those names. I found this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-pricing-tiers) that describes the pricing tiers. Is there anywhere can I get the list of sku_name and its details on a single link or page?

It is mentioned that the sku_name is of this form mentioned below:

> sku_name - (Required) Specifies the SKU Name for this MySQL Server.
> The name of the SKU, follows the tier + family + cores pattern (e.g.
> B_Gen4_1, GP_Gen5_8).

But, from where do we get the list of options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I always use `az-cli` to get this kind of information.

You can search for `az <service> sku` on google and it will usually point you in the right direction.

For Mysql you have:

```
az mysql server list-skus --location [--subscription]
```

eg.

```
az mysql server list-skus --location westeurope -o table
```

outputs

```
SKU         Tier             VCore    Generation
----------  ---------------  -------  ------------
B_Gen5_1    Basic            1        Gen5
B_Gen5_2    Basic            2        Gen5
GP_Gen5_2   GeneralPurpose   2        Gen5
GP_Gen5_4   GeneralPurpose   4        Gen5
GP_Gen5_8   GeneralPurpose   8        Gen5
GP_Gen5_16  GeneralPurpose   16       Gen5
GP_Gen5_32  GeneralPurpose   32       Gen5
GP_Gen5_64  GeneralPurpose   64       Gen5
MO_Gen5_2   MemoryOptimized  2        Gen5
MO_Gen5_4   MemoryOptimized  4        Gen5
MO_Gen5_8   MemoryOptimized  8        Gen5
MO_Gen5_16  MemoryOptimized  16       Gen5
MO_Gen5_32  MemoryOptimized  32       Gen5
```

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't find-able on the azure site docs.

Answer (score 1):

For Flexible Server, you can call the [Location Based Capabilities - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/mysql/flexibleserver/location-based-capabilities/list).

> Get capabilities at specified location in a given subscription.

For Single Server, use [Location Based Performance Tier - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/mysql/singleserver/location-based-performance-tier/list).

> List all the performance tiers at specified location in a given subscription.

Comment: The sku_name required by the terraform script is available in the second link on your answer. The value of 'id' is the required value. Thanks. Pointing the link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/mysql/singleserver/location-based-performance-tier/list

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to the official terraform documentation of [azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/postgresql_flexible_server).

The mapping is explained there. From Azure GUI you can find out the options available and then convert it to the mapping that terraform supports.

[image]

az cli also works but from my experience it doesn't show all the options available.